# Strong typed Flow

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am trying my hands on the Akka Stream DSL.
The thing that I can not get to compile is strong typed `Flow`s.
For `Zip` I do the following and it compiles fine:

```
val fanIn = builder.add(Zip[LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData])
```

For `Flow` however I cannot seem to get it working as desired since the following does not compile:

```
val encryptLoginData = builder.add(Flow[(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData), LoginCommand.UserData])
```

From the error message I cannot really tell, what I am doing wrong.

I noticed that `apply` is only taking a single type, but how is this supposed to show mapping between in <-> out?

Any hints on what I am doing wrong, or how this is supposed to be declared?

Answer (score 1):

Define your flow in the following manner:

```
val flow =                 
  Flow[(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData)]
    .map { (response, user) =>
      // do something with response and/or user that returns a LoginCommand.UserData
    } // Flow[(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData), LoginCommand.UserData, _]

fanIn.out ~> flow
```

The [`Flow.apply[T]`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow$.html) method, as the Scaladoc indicates, "returns a `Flow` which outputs all its inputs." This is the most basic `Flow` and serves as a building block for more complex `Flow`s. Typically, one needs to do more than merely output all the input elements; the common use case is to define a `Flow` that transforms the input in some way and outputs the result of that transformation. Your attempt to add the following `Flow`...

```
Flow[(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData), LoginCommand.UserData]
```

...suggests that you want to take an input of type `(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData)` and output a `LoggingCommand.UserData`. However, in order to do so, you have to define as part of the `Flow` *how* you want to transform an input element of type `(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData)` to a `LoginCommand.UserData`.

Comment: This may work but frankly to me totally defeats the purpose of a straight forward and understandable Graph definition.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the answer by @JeffreyChung I am reconsidering whether `Flow` is the best use here.
I now tried to go with the more basic `FlowShape`, which at least compiles.

```
    val encryptIn = Inlet[(LoginResponse, LoginCommand.UserData)]("EncryptInput")
    val encryptOut = Outlet[LoginCommand.UserData]("EncryptOutput")
    val encryptLoginData = FlowShape(encryptIn, encryptOut)
```

Not as elegant as I want it to be but neither is any solution I have seen using `Flow`.

So is this the intended way of using the DSL?